# Buffer Problems While Using Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, buffer

I've created a model that is supposed to allow a user to select an area of road and will then highlight the attributes within a user-specified buffer distance from the selected area. This is what I've made: [image]

However, it doesn't show the actual buffer part of it. The final product is supposed to have the area of road and the attributes within the buffer distance show up (which it is doing), but it doesn't show the buffer:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the CSRS_0RN_NER_Buffer writing to a file anywhere? Or is it just temporary? If it's temporary change it to write to a permanent file. Then you'll have the buffer and can add it to your project.

Comment: It's supposed to be a a temporary file but if it's set to that it doesn't show up :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it'll show up if it is set to be temporary. I assume you want it temporary so that if another selection is made and the tool is run again, only the new buffer shows.  One possibility, you could add a step to your model that, if a buffer exists, deletes the existing buffer before running.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the CSRS_0RN_NER_Buffer element and choose "Add To Display"

That will work for the dataset if it's written to disk or "in_memory"