# ModelBuilder Tool produces different results when using Run Button and running as a tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I found out that I can run a tool I created in ModelBuilder by clicking the run button after clicking to edit the tool. However, it doesn't produce the same results if I run the tool after clicking on it using the ArcCatalog window.

This doesn't work:

[image]

But this does:

[image]

Correct Output:

[image]

Incorrect Output:

[image]

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: Do you supply all the parameters when running the tool from the Catalog window? What kind of error do you get? How do you justify whether the model run successfully or not?

Comment: The user has to input the selecting features, the input feature layer, the selection type and the buffer radius. It's not so much an error that I get, but I expect the buffer layer to appear and it doesn't while using the Catalog window (it does when I click run in ModelBuilder). I know the model has run successfully when the buffer layer appears.

Comment: Can you publish a screenshot of the model? I am suspecting something is missing when setting the output to be added to display (either in model parameter) or in ArcMap > Geoprocessing menu > GP options). I've seen this kind of behavior earlier and had to fix this with adding an additional step on copying the output result to in_memory with Copy Features to force this to show up in the TOC.

Comment: If you re-start arcmap /aAc catalog, does it work the  1st time from the catalog window?  Also, I'm assuming this is your model? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132128/buffer-problems-while-using-model-builder

Comment: It doesn't work when restarted, and yes that's my model!

Answer (score 1):

I made the output feature class of the buffer portion of my tool (CSRS_ORN_NER_Buffer%n%) a model parameter, and even though when I run it it says theres a datum conflict, it seems to work fine through both the ArcCatalog window and ModelBuilder application.

[image]

[image]